# WindowLevel for UITextField's custom input view

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uialertview, uiwindow

Hope to find a workaround on setting `windowLevel` for my custom `inputView`.

**Scenario:** Using `PKHUD` in the project. It's window level is `UIWindowLevelNormal + 1.0`. I can change this if needed. I'm showing a custom input view for my textfields. Everything works fine except only when I want to show `PKHUD` loading indicator, `UIAlertController` & Custom InputView in the same place.

Showing progress indicator while making server api call when the user entered the content in textfield and tapped "GO". I'm not resigning the keyboard.

So, once I get an error from server, hiding the `PKHUD` & showing the `UIAlertController`. But, `UIAlertController` shows behind my custom keyboard. Any help would be appreciated showing the `UIAlertController` before the custom keyboard input view without resigning it.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. Did you figure it out?

Comment: @DPR I added an answer about what I did. Please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find a workaround. But, I got an advice from an expert. He said to not mess with a `WindowLevel`. `Keyboard` is a top level window and Apple made it there for a reason.

So, whenever we show a progress indicator or alert, we must resign the keyboard and invoke again if it is needed.